# javascript get current datetime

Tags: javascript

Good evening,

I am writing server application that will be running on node websocket and im having hard time processing dates.

This is piece of code that i wrote:

```
var getDatetime = function() {

    var checkLength = function(part) {
        return (part < 10) ? '0' + part : part;
    };

    var date = new Date(),
        year = date.getFullYear(),
        month = checkLength(date.getMonth()),
        day = checkLength(date.getDay()),
        hour = checkLength(date.getHours()),
        minute = checkLength(date.getMinutes()),
        second = checkLength(date.getSeconds());

    return day + '-' + month + '-' + year + ' ' + hour + ':' + minute + ':' + second;
};
```

It pains me to use it like that, im no pro with js so im asking, is there a method like in php `date('d-m-Y H:i:s', time())` with which you can get current datetime in nice and clean way instead of doing this the way i showed?

Comment: did you have a look at [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). It can be deployed both on front end and nodejs server. Here's the [install instruction](http://momentjs.com/docs/) for nodejs.

Comment: perfect, this is what i was in need of ;)

Answer (score 1):

With the Javascript constructor, [date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), under the Conversion getter section of the page linked to, there are several options for converting the format such as date.doDateString(). This will create a human-readable string, and with it being a string it can be cut up and re-arranged as needed with the use of sub strings.

```
var a = new Date();
console.log(a); // Wed March 25th 2015 16:10:38GMT -0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

With AngularJS you have an easy way to show dates which are in the epoch function, with the [date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date).